# ESP12e: analog reading not working with voltage divider

Tags: sensor, analog, esp8266

I'm trying to read from an analog sensor (a capacitive soil moisture sensor). I'm using a ESP12E, not a development board, so the ADC pin can only take 1V max. Since my sensor can output up to 3V, I need a voltage divider to not fry my board.

Here is my wiring:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mhiu.jpg

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3JC0O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Could you please confirm the wiring is ok?

I use micropython and the following code to read from the sensor:

```
from machine import Pin, ADC
from time import sleep

pot = ADC(0)

while True:
    pot_value = pot.read()

    print(pot_value)

    sleep(1)
```

However, the analog reading is always 0. When I disconnect the ADC pin, I get other, fluctuating values. So I think the problem comes from my voltage divider.

The sensor works with a ESP32 devkit board, so the problem doesn't come fro m the sensor (the devkit board has a voltage divider, so I didn't need to make one myself).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to try to decipher a poorly lit photograph of a breadboard. Use the built-in schematic editor to provide a proper schematic of your system.

Comment: Not to mention that having a schematics will most likely allow you to find the problem yourself right away

Comment: I didn't know there was a built-in schematic editor. I edited my question. I did my best, I'm a beginner in electronics. Could you still have a look at the picture though? Maybe you'll spot something oddly wrong with how I wired the thing.

Comment: A capacitive sensor might have a very high output impedance and your potential divider would virtually kill any signals coming from it.

Comment: ah yes that's probably that. Measuring the voltage directly from the sensor gives me ~2.5V, measuring the output from the voltage divider gives me 7mV...What can I do to fix that?

Comment: share sensor specs to show impedance , buffer signal with high impedance divider  but 7mV/(100//220=68) = 0.1uA or 2.5V/0.1uA = 25MegOhm source impedance.   Do you know Ohm's Law yet?

Comment: you can try increasing resistor values. but most likely it won't be enough as at some point the impedance will become too high for analog input. Your best bet is to use OP amp buffer.

Comment: ... or rather OP amp in attenuator configuration. It will deal with impedance and reduce output range at the same time.

Comment: The sensor is one of these: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/DFRobot%20PDFs/SEN0193_Web.pdf (well, a chinese clone) so not sure I can get the precise specs. I got the divider to work, by using 2x 220k ohm resistors as R1 and a 470k ohm as R2. I span the range 420/975 mv (in water, in air) vs 1.2/2.5V (water, air) directly from the sensor. Thanks all for spotting impedance was the problem.

Comment: You should have provided this info from the beginning. The DFRobot site has all the information you need, including [schematics](https://github.com/Arduinolibrary/DFRobot_Capacitive_Soil_Moisture_Sensor/raw/master/SEN0193%20%20Capacitive%20Soil%20Moisture%20SensorV1.0.PDF). The TLC555 timer basically pumps a capacitor through 10K resistor... and then you pretty much short it to the ground with 320 Ohm